# Meaning and usage of "I'm game"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "I'm game" mean and what is its correct usage?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`I'm game` means that `I am up for the challenge`, but arguably more commonly, `I agree`...

> Q: Fancy going for a drink?
>
> A: Sure, I'm game...

or

> Q: I was thinking of going shopping. Do
>   you want to come?
>
> A: Yes, I'm game...

As for correct usage, as with most idioms, use it as you will... there is no correct usage as such.

Comment: "As for correct usage, as with most idioms, use it as you will... there is no correct usage as such."  What does this mean?  There is certainly an appropriate time and manner to use idioms, and an inappropriate one.

Comment: That it is situation dependent and people are creative with their use of language?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Idioms, by definition, have no 'rules'. They convey a figurative meaning which is different to the literal meaning, and they are accepted through common use. Most people understand how 'I am game' is commonly used and intended, but there is nothing to stop someone extending or even completely re-inventing its use. So for idioms there is *common* usage rather than *correct* usage.

Comment: @CJM: "Idioms, by definition, have no 'rules'." Yes they do, but they can depend on the idiom you are using.  Saying "there is no correct usage" implies that you can use "I'm game" however you want.  But, in fact, you can't use it to mean "that's a good point", for example.  You can't say "I'm game" if you are talking about someone else, you have to say "he's game" or "she's game".  So, clearly, there are rules.

Comment: @Rhodri/@Kosmonaut: Idioms 'break the rules' by purporting to mean something beyond the literal. And idiom is only an idiom if its meaning is commonly understood. 'I'm game' could mean 'That is a good point' is enough people understood it so. In my opinion, idioms (like slang and dialects) already work outside the rules of language and therefore you have more freedom. Of course there are limits; but if you take my 'Idioms have no rules' too literally, you are going to struggle with idioms themselves! ;)

Comment: @CJM, that logic doesn't make any sense.

By that standard, *nothing* is English is correct, but only "common". As a descriptivist, I actually believe that correctness is (in an ultimate sense, not case-by-case) defined by usage -- but that doesn't mean idioms don't have a correct or standard usage, or that they have no rules -- it's just that these rules are dictated by common understanding (just like everything else in English).

What makes idioms idiomatic is not that they don't have rules, but they they form semantic *units* not necessarily decomposable *using* standard grammar rules.

Comment: For me "I am up for the challenge" or "I am in."

Comment: Worth noting is the British TV show "[Are You] [Game for a Laugh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WfiSv2Tj10)" which is an encouragement to join in and laugh, it was a hidden camera show; demanding that the victims be ready to laugh at themselves, ie be game. I think there was a USA version, and probably others, too.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid to go down the path of explaining correct usage of an idiom, so I will just tell you how I use it! I think of it as another way of saying, "That sounds good to me." Another phrase people often use is, "I'm down," and I would say that these two can be used interchangeably. Here is an example:

Q: Do you want to go see a movie tonight?
Possible replies all meaning the same thing:
A: Sure, I'm game.
A: Sure, I'm down.
A: Sure, that sounds good to me.

That last one is a mouthful, so you can see the appeal of the first two!

Comment: What does "I'm down" mean?

Comment: "I'm down" is a short way of saying "You can put me down on the list", which is another idiomatic way of saying "Yes" to something.

Answer (score -2):

"I'm game" could mean "I'm very smelly."

Comment: Actually, wouldn't that need to be "I'm gamey" to mean smelly?

Comment: @KristinaLopez, A contraction of "gamy"?