# Usage of the word "game"

Tags: meaning

I often hear this word 'game'. One of the questions in the site [talks about the meaning of "I am game"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/what-does-im-game-mean-and-whats-its-correct-usage). Users have replied that "I am game" implies that I am up for the challenge.

But I would like to know the exact meaning and context regarding the usage of the word 'game'. I've also seen it being used in Eminem's rap songs saying "I am married to a game".

So what exactly is this word word 'game'? What is its context and usage?

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what you are asking here. If you want every possible usage of a word, including the various idioms, compounds and phrases it can contribute to, then you are asking a very vast question. This would benefit from being made a little more specific. My answer refers to the lyric you asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the lyric you are talking of comes from the track "Not Afraid". If that is the case, then it is in fact:

*married to the game*

Here, **the game** refers to an industry, in this case the music industry; many hip-hop artists talk of *The Rap Game* and it simply means the genre/industry that they are a part of.

To be *married to the game* then, means to be so serious about your work, so committed to your job, that it is like a marriage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the bold text I just fell foul of the other definition of the game http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game)

Comment: Haha, and now so have we all!

Answer (score 2):

As an adjective, *game* means "eager and willing to do something new or challenging."

> They were game for anything after the traumas of Monday.

Comment: What does "Married to a game" refer to?

Comment: That's a different meaning. Notice how it is an adjective in one (I am game) and a noun in the other (I am married to a game).

Answer (score 0):

On the lighter side (and because it's too long to fit as a comment)...

> A woman was married to a lazy man.  He never mowed the lawn, he never took out the garbage, he rarely kept a job for more than six months, and was not someone who could generally be considered a 'good provider'.  One day, when she was at wit's end, she yelled at her husband, "If you're not going to try to find a job that will put food on our table, the least you could do is go out in the woods and shoot some ***game***!"
>
> The hen-pecked man collected his hunting gear and walked off into the woods.
>
> After some hours he came into a clearing where a beautiful young woman was sunning herself on a blanket.  "Are you ***game***?" he asked her.
>
> The young woman looked up at him provocatively and said "I sure am."
>
> ...So he shot her.

Comment: 'Being game' when applied to a women has a slightly different meaning !