# What does “it’s no game” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I’ve recently heard David Bowie’s song where he sings

> To be insulted by these fascists
>       Is so degrading and it’s no game.

Is *it’s no game* some kind of a metaphor or a widely used idiom, or maybe some kind of this particular song specific expression? Or should it be simply taken literally?

Comment: I think (in this case) it stands for "it's not cool" but it's an expression that could mean anything. For example _Public Enemy_'s song _He got game_ uses (sort of) the same expression and it stands for "he's got a skill" (not in a particular field)

Comment: It could simply mean "it's no fun" as well as the literal meaning of not being a game. This is why "Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature" (which includes song lyrics at the lower end of the spectrum) is [off-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having a look here:
[I'm Game](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/what-does-im-game-mean-and-whats-its-correct-usage)

And Since its an Idiom there is really no correct way of using it. A few examples:

Its not cool:

> People making fun of the handicap! its no game.

Its not worth/fun/cool:

> Friend1:Wanna go TP'ing a house?
>   Friend2:No man, its no game.

disagreeing:

> Friend1: You going to the shooting range this weekend?
>   Friend2: Nah man, my inlaws coming in this weekend so its no game for me.

I think the 2nd example is of relevance to you.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1980s people in action movies would say "this is no game" to mean "this is serious." It has nothing to do with the playa/hustla sense of game.